# Show website activities on Facebook timeline?

Tags: php, facebook-timeline

How can I show website activity on the Facebook timeline?

I integrated Facebook API and [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect). Now, if any new user uploads a video on the website then I want to display this activity on the Facebook log. What function of Facebook API can I use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Open Graph Actions and Objects. I recommend you create:

- A video object
- An "uploaded" action as well as utilising the built-in "watch" action

There is a full and more than helpful [tutorial right here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/). Things to consider:

- You need to request `publish_actions` permission from users of your website, if you are already using Facebook Login, then this is a simple matter of adding it to the list of Permissions that you are requesting
- Publish an uploaded action for every new video uploaded, make sure you get explicit consent from the user to do so, so that you can use the `fb:explicitly_shared` parameter.
- Use the watch action for any videos that people watch on your website.

Comment: your reply is helpful. I gone through given links. It also required some meta tags. I need functionality similar to facebook like button For example see this link : http://realtybrooklyn.com/blog/     when user click on FB like button on page, he gets some relevant information about blog on his facebook wall or time line. How I can modify the text of posting message.I also want to avoid post message option along with like button.

Comment: The text posted to Facebook is derived from the Open Graph tags included on the page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/
  
You can see the debug results of that site you linked, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frealtybrooklyn.com%2Fblog%2F

The post message box is determined by the size of the Like button, as per the second FAQ here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#faq